# Video Hidden w/ Visible Controls

Tags: html5-video, controls, visibility

I'm currently working on a project where I have an embedded video(website) with "visibility: hidden". However, I still wish to have the controls for the video visible. I know I can make my own controls but I was wondering if anybody knew a different way such as:

- Only making the video hidden, but the keep the controls visible
- Making video(with controls) hidden and duplicating the controls somehow

If neither of these are possible and I have to make my own controls, is there an easier way to clone the default control UI for  players than making incremental edits to make them match?

I'm pretty much a noob so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls are part of the video element, so showing or hiding it is an all-or-nothing deal. You've got to provide your own controls.

The good news is there are several tools that will do that for you, and some of them come with options for styling the controls. Look into:

- Video.js
- Mediaelement.js
- jPlayer
- jwPlayer